# Trying to set the time since midnight Sunday for java calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I have the time in milliseconds and I set it to Calendar object for a particular time.
This initial time is just supposed to be an estimate of the time, but the actual time is based upon the time of week in milliseconds since Sunday at midnight.

So I need to somehow set the time of week for the Calendar object but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

Is there a slick way to do this? Am I using the best Java object.
I haven't done Java in a long time so it is pretty new to me.

Here's an example : There are 2 things that happen. 1) GM Time in ms for the apoximate time. 01/03/2001 01:00:00 Tuesday. Then I get event 2) GMT Time in milliseconds since Sunday at Midnight (01/01/2001) ) 0:00:00. Lets just say it has been 20000 ms since that date. So now I need to know how to set the actual date /time since midnight, so I can see what that actual time is

Comment: What version of Java are you using? If you can use Java 8, use the new `java.time` package. Otherwise, can you use Joda Time? (An external date/time API, much better than `java.util.Calendar`.)

Comment: I'm using Java 7 and I don't think I can't add any external APIs. Thanks for the ideas thogh!

Comment: Okay, in that case, you should probably stick with `Calendar` and maybe `Date`. What time zone are you interested in? What do you want to happen if there's a daylight-saving transition? You should supply sample input and desired output - your question isn't terribly clear at the moment.

Comment: All of the times are GMT. The original time should be within a few seconds or minutes of the actual time that is set. So basically you get a GMT time in milliseconds that supplies the basic Date/hour/seconds/milliseconds of the time I am interested in. Then I get an offset into that week since Sunday at midnight in milliseconds.  I use this offset to caclculate the actual precise desired time.

Comment: So which Sunday midnight are you interested in? The most recent one? The next one? Something else? Again, it's really not clear at the moment.

Comment: Here's an example : There are 2 things that happen. a

Comment: Please edit this information into the question, instead of just as comments.

Comment: Here's an example : There are 2 things that happen. 1) GM Time in ms for the apoximate time. 01/03/2001 01:00:00 Tuesday.   Then I get event 2) GMT Time in milliseconds since Sunday at Midnight (01/01/2001) ) 0:00:00.   Lets  just say it has been 20000 ms since that date.  So now I need to know how to set the actual date /time since midnight, so I can see what that actual time is

Comment: So basically your setting the current time of week since midnight and  then seeing what that time/date is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar nowCal = (however you get/set the time you care about, as a Calendar)
long now = nowCal.getTimeInMillis();
long millis_today = now % 86400;
long millis_in_days = (nowCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - Calendar.SUNDAY) * 86400L;
long time_since_midnight_sunday = millis_in_days + millis_today;
```